# How to add new array to existing arrray?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've an following array called `$title`:

```
Array
(
    [pt_id] => 4
    [pt_doc_title] => Solapur IT Park
    [pt_doc_id] => 1
    [delete_flag] => 
    [pt_doc_file_iname] => Array.php
)
```

But I want this array in below form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pt_doc_id] => 1
            [pt_id] => 4
            [pt_doc_title] => Solapur IT Park
            [pt_doc_file_iname] => 
            [pt_doc_added_date] => 1390390546
            [pt_doc_updated_date] => 1390390704
        )

)
```

How can I achieve this? Though here array key is zero I'm having another key values in my hand. The issue I'm facing is how to add these key numbers (as 0 is added above)? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

save your array in this format.

```
  $title = array();

  $title[] = array(
        'pt_doc_id'=>'1',
        'pt_id'=>'4',
        'pt_doc_title'=>'Solapur IT Park',
        'pt_doc_file_iname'=>'',
        'pt_doc_added_date'=>'1390390546',
        'pt_doc_updated_date'=>'1390390704'
    );
```

set your array format like this.

i hop this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array1 & array2

```
<?php
$array1=Array
(
    'pt_id' => '4',
    'pt_doc_title' => 'Solapur IT Park'
);

$array2[0]=$array1;
print_r($array2);
?>
```

Will give you output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pt_id] => 4
            [pt_doc_title] => Solapur IT Park
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Live demo : https://eval.in/93311

use `array_push`  it will auto indexing your array. if you have multi-dimensional array then you can run this steps in a loop.

```
 $arr =array
    (
        "pt_id" => 4,
        "pt_doc_title" =>" Solapur IT Park",
        "pt_doc_id" => 1,
        "delete_flag" => '',
        "pt_doc_file_iname" => "Array.php"
    );
     $arr['pt_doc_added_date'] = 1390390546; //add your new element
     $arr['pt_doc_updated_date'] = 1390390704;
    $result = array();
    array_push($result,$arr); //push this array in result array
    print_r($result);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pt_id] => 4
            [pt_doc_title] =>  Solapur IT Park
            [pt_doc_id] => 1
            [delete_flag] => 
            [pt_doc_file_iname] => Array.php
            [pt_doc_added_date] => 1390390546
            [pt_doc_updated_date] => 1390390704
        )

)
```